# PowerBI bar chart top 15 and remaining amount for 3 years

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I need a bar chart in powerbi. but i want it to show only the top 15 values as well as the summed up remaining amount. the remaining amount should be listed as the last one in the chart.

i tried to create a measure for the top 15 and the remaining. i also then created the sorting based on the same criteria. now i have problems with circular relationships. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If you look around on YouTube, Alberto Ferrari (sqlbi) walks you through this scenario.  "Filter Top 3 Products with a row for Others using DAX in PowerBI" is the title of the video.